# What is prefix L for amino acids?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I know the "L" at the beginning of amino acids pointed out to show the substance is digestive. 
 The thing I don't know is that what is the "L" stands for and how it works.

Comment: The stereochemistry at the chiral centre of each individual amino acid can be D or L or racemic. L is the naturally occuring form so most digestive enzyme are set up to metabolise polypeptides made of L amino acids.

Comment: Originating from right and left, though due to nomenclature stratification d and l labels do not always correspond to the actual verse, identified by (+) or minus instead.

Answer (score 0):

From [Chemgapedia](http://www.chemgapedia.de/vsengine/vlu/vsc/de/ch/8/bc/vlu/proteine/aminosaeuren.vlu/Page/vsc/de/ch/8/bc/proteine/aminos_u_einleit/d_l.vscml.html):

Most of the aminoacids in nature have different spatial structures. These properties are due to a chiral center (on the C-alpha atom), which has four different substituents. One differentiates a D-form (from Latin *dextro* = right) in which the amino group of the C-alpha atom in the Fischer projection to the right, and an L-shape (from *levo* = left), in which it is to the left. 
 Since they are the same molecules that differ only in their spatial structure, they also have identical chemical and physical properties. With one exception: enantiomers turn the plane of oscillation of polarized light either to the left (-) or to the right (+). 
 But attention: One can not conclude from the D / L-form on the rotation characteristics +/-, since the division D / L refers only to the arrangement of the substituents at the C-alpha-atom!

See the link above for pictures to support the explanation.

Comment: BTW, *dextro* is the root of the word *dexterous*, implying the person is skilled ("right" handed). `Levo` is a synonym for `sinister`, or left handed.